# Initializing and Updating Fragment's Data with ViewPager Bundle or Getters

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having some difficulties grasping the correct way to create fragments using the ViewPager, initialize their data and then eventually update their data.

The challenge is where do I stick the data structure? Currently it is passed in from a previous activity into my main activity as a bundle and initialzed like so (Where mTitles is a list of my tab titles and the Fragment titles, and mData is a hashmap containing a list of data for each fragment

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Parcelable>> mData = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Parcelable>>();
ArrayList<String> mTitles = new ArrayList<String>()

private void initializeData(Bundle extras, String[] keys) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            mData.put(keys[i], extras.getParcelableArrayList(keys[0]));
        }
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager, keys);
        }
    }
```

Then I call the setupViewPager to initialize the fragments and their data from the data structure.

```
public class FragmentObserver extends Observable {
    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        setChanged(); // Set the changed flag to true, otherwise observers won't be notified.
        super.notifyObservers();
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(Object object) {
        setChanged(); // Set the changed flag to true, otherwise observers won't be notified.
        super.notifyObservers(object);
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager, String[] tabs) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        b1.putString("title", tabs[i]);
        Log.d("ADAPTER: ", "putting " + tabs[i]);
        b1.putParcelableArrayList(tabs[i], mData.get(tabs[i]));

        ListFragment f1 = new ListFragment();
        f1.setArguments(b1);

        mTitles.add(tabs[i]);
        adapter.addFragment(f1, tabs[i]);
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);          
}
class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    private Observable mObservers = new FragmentObserver();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        this.mFragments.add(fragment);
        this.mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    public Fragment getItemByTitle(String title) {
        int index = this.mFragmentTitles.indexOf(title);
        return (index > 0) ? getItem(index) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = this.mFragments.get(position);
        mObservers.addObserver((Observer) f);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return this.mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }

    public void updateFragments(SessionInfo session) {
        mObservers.notifyObservers(session);

    }
}
```

Fragment Code:

```
ArrayList<Info> mDatas;
public ListFragment(){
        super();

}
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
    View root = getView();
    // Update your views here.
    Log.d("OBSERVER", "called update for: " + ((SessionInfo) data).getActivity());
    Log.d("OBSERVER", "I am " + title);

//        SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter a = ((SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter)rv.getAdapter());
//        a.insertValueAt(0, (SessionInfo) data);
//
//        a.notifyItemInserted(0);

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_session_list, container, false);

    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    mDatas = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(title);
//        SessionInfo first = sessions.get(0);
//        Log.i("FRAG", first.getActivity());
    this.title = title;


    return rv;
}
```

The problem and my question is what happens when I need to update a fragments data structure?  Currently it is stored in the Activity class so I update it there, and then call the observer update method to pass the data to the fragment.  But I get a null pointer error if I need to update Fragment 3 and I have not scrolled my ViewPager to 3 yet so it is not initialized and of course has no Observer yet. How do I update that fragments data?

Is this Observer pattern pron to memory leaks?

Should I just be holding a reference to Activity and call a getter method for my data rather then sending it as a bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Basically pass your HashMap> mData to Adapter and from adapter setArguments() with relevant data on each fragment. That way relevant data stay with relevant object.

Comment: Yes, but how to update the Fragment data if the fragment hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Always set updated value in adapter, and you can create fragment instance in getItem() and setArguments() every time you create. Just like tutorial link I gave.